# Create a PHP nested array from array with unknown number of values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, nested

Say I have this as a PHP array

```
$my = array('Google','Api','Key');
```

How can I create a nested array so it ends up like this

```
$new = array('Google'=>array('Api'=>array('key'=>'Some Value');
```

It needs to be dynamic as I will have no idea how many elements $my holds.

I have spent 8 hours trying and failed any help would be appreciated.

I have edited this as I need the final element in the $my array to have a value set. How would I do this.

Thanks

Comment: To be honest Matt I have tried so many things I have got myself all confussed. My head tells me I need to use recursion. The trouble I am having is getting the previous arrays I have added. I seem to always end up with a 1 dimensional array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function build_recursive_array($array)
{
    if(sizeof($array) < 1) return array();

    $key = array_shift($array);
    return array($key => build_recursive_array($array));
}
print_r(build_recursive_array(array('Google','Api','Key')));
```

Comment: +1 | Well done, in before me. ;P I used `empty()` rather than `sizeof()` though.

Comment: Alex, how would I add a value to the last element in the $my array. Thanks

Comment: @Chris The line that says `return array()` is `Key`'s value. You can change that.

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen , but how do I know it is the last element in the array ? Would I yet the count of $my and use an if statement so when it's on the last element to not do build_recursive_array($array) but $key => "Some Value"

Comment: @Chris That line _only_ returns if it is the last element. Just change it to `if(sizeof($array) < 1) return 'Some Value';` and you'll be good.

Comment: Thanks, just got there before you.